# Analytical solution to a matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to solve the following matrix equation $(I-X^{-1}BX^{-1})(X-C)=0$ where $X,B,C$ are positive definite and $X$ is unknown. Two obvious solutions are $X=C$ and $X=B^{\frac{1}{2}}$. We also assume that $BC=CB$.

I was wondering whether the other solutions to the above can be computed analytically?

Comment: There are a number of analytically obtainable solutions in the specific case $BC = CB$.

Comment: Can you please provide those references

Comment: I have added the condition that BC=CB now

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case $BC = CB$, it is easy to find analytic solutions. Since $B$ and $C$ commute, there is a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}BP= D_B$ and $P^{-1}CP =  D_C$, where $D_B$ and $D_C$ are diagonal matrices. So, if we choose $X$ to satisfy $X = PD_XP^{-1}$ for some diagonal matrix $D_X$, the equation reduces to
$$
[I - (P D_X^{-1}P^{-1})(P D_B^{-1}P^{-1})(P D_X^{-1}P^{-1})][(P D_X^{-1}P^{-1}) - (P D_C^{-1}P^{-1})] = P(I - D_X^{-1}D_BD_X^{-1})(D_X - D_C)P^{-1} = 0
$$
All diagonal matrices commute with each other, so this can be further simplified to
$$
(D_X^2 - D_B)(D_X - D_C) = 0
$$
Now, letting $\lambda_{Bi}$ be the entries on the diagonal of $D_B$, and similar for $D_C$ and $D_X$, that equation will be satisfied if, for all $i$, $\lambda_{Xi}^2 = \lambda_{Bi}$ or $\lambda_{Xi} = \lambda_{Ci}$. By choosing one of those two for each $i$, we can create $2^n$ (not necessarily distinct) solutions $X = P^{-1}D_XP$, where $n$ is the size of the matrices.

Comment: Thanks! Can there exist other X which is not of the form X=PD_XP^{-1} which might satisfy the matrix equation?